# Kotlin error: Expected 2 parameters of types android.widget.CompoundButton!, kotlin.Boolean

Tags: kotlin

I have a Kotlin error saying

```
Expected 2 parameters of types android.widget.CompoundButton!, kotlin.Boolean
```

The red squiggly line is at the first `{` in the code below:

```
    alarmSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    { 
        fun onCheckedChanged(buttonView: CompoundButton, isChecked: Boolean)
        {
```

I tried:

- `buttonView: !CompoundButton,` (says "Expecting comma or )" )
- `buttonView: CompoundButton!,` (says "Unexpected Token")
- `buttonView!: CompoundButton,` (says "Expecting comma or )" )
- `!buttonView: CompoundButton,` (says "Expecting comma or )" )
- `buttonView: CompoundButton?,` (says "Expected 2 parameters of types android.widget.CompoundButton!, kotlin.Boolean" )

The official Kotlin docs say:

> Notation for Platform Types
>
> As mentioned above, platform types cannot be mentioned explicitly in
> the program, so there’s no syntax for them in the language.
> Nevertheless, the compiler and IDE need to display them sometimes (in
> error messages, parameter info etc), so we have a mnemonic notation
> for them:
>
> - T! means “T or T?”,
> - (Mutable)Collection! means “Java collection of
>   T may be mutable or not, may be nullable or not”,
> - Array<(out) T>!
>   means “Java array of T (or a subtype of T), nullable or not”

I don't fully understand what the docs are saying. How would I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need the object keyword (`object:`) which is needed for creating an object of an anonymous class.

See [Object declaration](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions)

Try this:

```
alarmSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(object:OnCheckedChangeListener() {
  fun onCheckedChanged(buttonView:CompoundButton, isChecked:Boolean) {
    // whatever...
  }
})
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

We can also simplify the code using a lambda expression

```
alarmSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked -> /* whatever...*/ }
```

https://antonioleiva.com/functional-programming-android-kotlin-lambdas/

Answer (score 0):

```
checkboxQuickApproval.setOnCheckedChangeListener(object : CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
   override fun onCheckedChanged(buttonView: CompoundButton?, isChecked: Boolean) {
        if (isChecked) {
            viewModel.onChangeCheckboxValue(isChecked) 
        }
    }
})
```